# Default to content_type application/json with overriden isFatal from DefaultExceptionStrategy

Tags: spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I'd like to not require my clients to provide content_type application/json but just default to it.     I got this working.

I also tried to combine with another example to implement a custom isFatal(Throwable t) from ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler.   I can get my custom error handler to fire,  but then it seems to require the content_type property again.    I can't figure out how to get them both to work at the same time.

Any ideas?

The below successfully works to not require content_type
**EDIT: The below code does not work as I thought.  An old message in the queue with the property content_type application/json must have been pulled in**

```
 @EnableRabbit
 @Configuration
 public class ExampleRabbitConfigurer implements 
 RabbitListenerConfigurer {

@Value("${spring.rabbitmq.host:'localhost'}")
private String host;

@Value("${spring.rabbitmq.port:5672}")
private int port;

@Value("${spring.rabbitmq.username}")
private String username;

@Value("${spring.rabbitmq.password}")
private String password;

@Autowired
private MappingJackson2MessageConverter mappingJackson2MessageConverter;

@Autowired
private DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory messageHandlerMethodFactory;

@Bean
public MappingJackson2MessageConverter mappingJackson2MessageConverter() {
   return new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
}

@Bean
public DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory messageHandlerMethodFactory() {
   DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory factory = new DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory();
   factory.setMessageConverter(mappingJackson2MessageConverter);
   return factory;
}

@Override
public void configureRabbitListeners(final RabbitListenerEndpointRegistrar registrar) {
   registrar.setMessageHandlerMethodFactory(messageHandlerMethodFactory);
}
```

The below here works to override isFatal() in ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler.   The SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory.setMessageConverter() seems like it should serve the same purpose as DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory.setMessageConverter().   Obviously this is not the case.

```
 @EnableRabbit
 @Configuration
 public class ExampleRabbitConfigurer {

@Value("${spring.rabbitmq.host:'localhost'}")
private String host;

@Value("${spring.rabbitmq.port:5672}")
private int port;

@Value("${spring.rabbitmq.username}")
private String username;

@Value("${spring.rabbitmq.password}")
private String password;

@Autowired
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

@Autowired
Jackson2JsonMessageConverter jackson2JsonConverter;

@Autowired
ErrorHandler amqpErrorHandlingExceptionStrategy;

@Bean
public Jackson2JsonMessageConverter jackson2JsonConverter() {
    return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
}

@Bean
public ErrorHandler amqpErrorHandlingExceptionStrategy() {
    return new ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler(new AmqpErrorHandlingExceptionStrategy());
}

@Bean
public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    factory.setMessageConverter(jackson2JsonConverter);
    factory.setErrorHandler(amqpErrorHandlingExceptionStrategy);
    return factory;
}


public static class AmqpErrorHandlingExceptionStrategy extends ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler.DefaultExceptionStrategy {

    private final Logger LOGGER = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Override
    public boolean isFatal(Throwable t) {

        if (t instanceof ListenerExecutionFailedException) {
            ListenerExecutionFailedException lefe = (ListenerExecutionFailedException) t;
            LOGGER.error("Failed to process inbound message from queue "
                    + lefe.getFailedMessage().getMessageProperties().getConsumerQueue()
                    + "; failed message: " + lefe.getFailedMessage(), t);
        }
        return super.isFatal(t);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an "after receive" `MessagePostProcessor` to add the `contentType` header to the inbound message.

Starting with version 2.0, you can add the MPP to the container factory.

For earlier versions you can reconfigure...

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So47424449Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So47424449Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry registry, RabbitTemplate template) {
        return args -> {
            SimpleMessageListenerContainer container =
                    (SimpleMessageListenerContainer) registry.getListenerContainer("myListener");
            container.setAfterReceivePostProcessors(m -> {
                m.getMessageProperties().setContentType("application/json");
                return m;
            });
            container.start();

            // send a message with no content type
            template.setMessageConverter(new SimpleMessageConverter());
            template.convertAndSend("foo", "{\"bar\":\"baz\"}", m -> {
                m.getMessageProperties().setContentType(null);
                return m;
            });
            template.convertAndSend("foo", "{\"bar\":\"qux\"}", m -> {
                m.getMessageProperties().setContentType(null);
                return m;
            });
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public Jackson2JsonMessageConverter converter() {
        return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    }

    @RabbitListener(id = "myListener", queues = "foo", autoStartup = "false")
    public void listen(Foo foo) {
        System.out.println(foo);
        if (foo.bar.equals("qux")) {
            throw new MessageConversionException("test");
        }
    }

    public static class Foo {

        public String bar;

        public String getBar() {
            return this.bar;
        }

        public void setBar(String bar) {
            this.bar = bar;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Foo [bar=" + this.bar + "]";
        }

    }

}
```

As you can see, since it modifies the source message, the modified header is available in the error handler...

> 2017-11-22 09:39:26.615  WARN 97368 --- [cTaskExecutor-1] ingErrorHandler$DefaultExceptionStrategy : Fatal message conversion error; message rejected; it will be dropped or routed to a dead letter exchange, if so configured: (Body:'{"bar":"qux"}' MessageProperties [headers={}, **contentType=application/json**, contentEncoding=UTF-8, contentLength=0, receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, priority=0, redelivered=false, receivedExchange=, receivedRoutingKey=foo, deliveryTag=2, consumerTag=amq.ctag-re1kcxKV14L_nl186stM0w, consumerQueue=foo]), contentType=application/json, contentEncoding=UTF-8, contentLength=0, receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, priority=0, redelivered=false, receivedExchange=, receivedRoutingKey=foo, deliveryTag=2, consumerTag=amq.ctag-re1kcxKV14L_nl186stM0w, consumerQueue=foo])

Comment: With 2.0 you can add the MPP to the container factory.

Comment: Thanks Gary, the afterReceivePostProcessor was exactly what I needed.  I was able to adapt your example into my code successfully.